# How to insert a bulk text into a text field in WatiN

Tags: c#, watin

Just wondering whether there is a way to insert a bulk text message into a text field in WatiN? I am looking for a fast method to insert data instead of using .TypeText function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `Value` property?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
txtFeild.SetAttributeValue("value", "your vaue");
```

to set the value of a textbox or textarea;